# ASP.Net.Core 2.2 Identity change ID from string to int

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to change the ID of the Users table from a string (GUID) to an int and really struggling. I have looked at lots of examples but they seem to be for earlier versions of Identity or vs and for numerous reasons they don't work.

I either get a compiler error

> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore 6[TUser,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserLogin,TUserToken]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

Or when I create the migration I still get a string column for the ID not an int as I was expecting.

**I'm using vs2019. Asp.Net.Core 2.2 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.2**

Can anyone help me out, please? Thanks!

Comment: There is a tutorial here: [Change the primary key type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-the-model).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First extend the `IdenityUser` class class as follows so that you can add custom properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

Then extend the `IdentityRole` class follows if you use `Role` in application too. You can keep this safely even you don't want to use it:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
}
```

Now your `ApplicationDbContext` should be as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Now in your `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 
}
```

Job done! Now run a brand new migration and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

@TanvirArjel solution also worked with .NET Core 3.1 in my project with modifications. I had added Identity through scaffolding.

Instead of editing ConfigureServices(), I edited IdentityHostingStartup.cs instead and mofified Configure() inside IdentityHostingStartup.cs:

```
 builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
 {
     services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDbContextConnection")));
     services.AddIdentity()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
              .AddDefaultUI(); //add default razor pages for identity (login, register, etc)
 });
```